# How to connect to flask application on EC2 linux?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

I have created a simple flask application running on EC2 linux, however I'm unable to access it using the EC2 instance public IP address. I have opened all the ports to all traffic on the EC2 SG and still times out try accessing the IP address from the browser.

Once I run `flask run`, it prompts with the message `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000` and if I run another terminal and `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000`, I get the response successfully.

It seems there's some missing link/ mapping between the instance's IP address and my flask app.

What configuration should I use to communicate with my flask application using the EC2 IP?

Sample code below:

```
from flask import Flask, Response
import time 
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    def gen():
        for c in 'Hello world!':
            yield c
            time.sleep(0.5)
    return Response(gen())

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: From where you're trying to connect? A local IP, another EC2 instance...?

Comment: I'm trying to connect from the internet (ie. my browser)

Comment: did you configured NACL and Security Groups properly? Are the subnet on which the EC2 instance is deployed associated with an Internet Gateway?

Comment: Yes, both are open. Infact, I can ping the EC2 instance from my local terminal successfully. 
It seems there's some configuration necessary on the actual flask application level.

Comment: Have you opened port 5000 for 0.0.0.0 on the security group. Also check if you have any other ec2 from where you can use the private ip of the ec2 instance and then do a curl

Comment: Yes, SG in/outbound has port range `All` on source 0.0.0.0/0. 
Tested and cannot successfully curl private IP of the instance from another EC2 instance in same vpc/subnet. Yes, the testing instance also has open SG/NACL's

Answer (score 0):

It seems that running the app like `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` has fixed the issue.